# Batch - What is the best way to get the duration of all the videos in a folder?

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg

For some reason, nothing in the nested for loop runs.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /F "delims=" %%J IN ('dir /b *mp4 *wmv *avi *flv *mkv *mov') DO (
    set x=%%J
    echo !x!
    FOR /F "tokens=" %%F IN ('ffprobe -i "!x!" -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0"') DO (
        echo %%F
        SET var=%%F
        SET time_raw=!var:~12,7!
        echo !var!
        )
)
```

The `ffprobe -i "!x!" -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0"` command works in a command window, so I am not sure why it is not working here. Are there any suggestion for where I am going wrong?

Comment: To begin with, you need to escape the unquoted `=` delimiters, i.e. change `format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0"`, to `format^=duration -v quiet -of csv^="p=0"`. Then you may also want to consider whether you really want just the thirteenth to nineteenth characters of the output.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I fixed it by changing "tokens=" to "delims=" in the nested for loop, and I did remove the substring portion.

Comment: I was leaving the `tokens`/`delims` advice, until after you had provided some confirmation of your substring manipulation of the string result. BTW `"tokens=*"` would have been adequate if your result did not begin with one or more whitespace characters.